# N64 Expansion Pak not recognized

Tags: nintendo-64

I recently started playing the N64 versions of Zelda after I found a console in working order. It appears to not be able to save, which I narrowed down to either the cartridge's battery or the Expansion Pak. When I went to try another game, I got a message saying that "The N64 Expansion Pak must be installed in the N64 for this game" (Majora's mask btw, I knew it would need it going in).

EDIT: I figured out that I needed to press Reset on the console for saving. Unfortunately it still isn't recognizing the expansion pak.

Problem: I have two Expansion Paks that I have tried with my console to no avail. I know there's the option of soldering new components onto the circuit board (which I may have to learn for the battery anyway), What steps should I try before just buying another console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BE very careful when buying from an online retailer. The one I found had a "Jumper / Expansion Pak." These are two very different things. The Jumper/terminator Pak is used exclusively to dead-end the circuit for functionality reasons, and has "ターミネータ パック" written on it. The Expansion/Kakucho Pak has "拡張パック" written on it. No kanji = no work